# extracitng movie IDs from IMDB

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to figure out how can I get only the id's of the movies from this page.

```
http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/2013-05/
```

I have this, but I cannot get it to work.

```
$content =  file_get_contents("http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/");

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Also I don't know much about DomDocument. This currently gets all the links on the page. However, I need to just get ids of the movies from the movie title links like

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1869716/
```

The id is

**tt1869716**

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is giving me headaches with code blocks in comments. Here's a Gist:

https://gist.github.com/ghalusa/5591124

Comment: Hello Gor, Thanks for this. I tested this and the result is overwhelming. It returned so many information. Can we get only the movie id's?

Comment: I haven't tested, but the answer below (from @enenen) looks like it takes care of things quite nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_url_contents($url) {
    $crl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

function getElementsByClassName(DOMDocument $DOMDocument, $ClassName)
{
    $Elements = $DOMDocument -> getElementsByTagName("*");
    $Matched = array();

    foreach($Elements as $node)
    {
        if( ! $node -> hasAttributes())
            continue;

        $classAttribute = $node -> attributes -> getNamedItem('class');

        if( ! $classAttribute)
            continue;

        $classes = explode(' ', $classAttribute -> nodeValue);

        if(in_array($ClassName, $classes))
            $Matched[] = $node;
    }

    return $Matched;
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$content =  get_url_contents("http://www.imdb.com/movies-in-theaters/"); 

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$elemsByClassName = getElementsByClassName($dom, 'overview-top'); 

foreach($elemsByClassName as $elem) {

    foreach ($elem->getElementsByTagName('a') as $a) {
        preg_match('/(title\/)([0-9A-Za-z]+)(\/)?/',$a->getAttribute('href'), $matches);

        echo $a->nodeValue. ' - ' . $matches[2] . '<br/>';
        break; // we need only the first A tag.
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 Star Trek Into Darkness (2013) - tt1408101
 Frances Ha (2012) - tt2347569
 Stories We Tell (2012) - tt2366450
 The Expatriate (2012) - tt1645155
 The English Teacher (2013) - tt2055765
 Augustine (2012) - tt2098628
 Black Rock (2012) - tt1930294
 State 194 (2012) - tt2324918
 Iron Man 3 (2013) - tt1300854
 The Great Gatsby (2013) - tt1343092
 Pain & Gain (2013) - tt1980209
 Peeples (2013) - tt1699755
 42 (2013) - tt0453562
 Oblivion (2013) - tt1483013
 The Croods (2013) - tt0481499
 The Big Wedding (2013) - tt1931435
 Mud (2012) - tt1935179
 Oz the Great and Powerful (2013) - tt1623205
```

Comment: Keith, upvote eneen's answer, yes? Because it works quite nicely :)